# Can't plot a bar chart

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I want to simply draw  plot. But I am having an interesting message instead of plot. It is not an error message, I have seen such a message before. The message is the following:

```
<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1c4150890>
```

The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,9,16]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to print a matplotlib-`Figure` object as a string (`print fig` or something). Is the code above really what you're executing?

I had to change it to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,4,9,16]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

to make it work:

[image: picture]

Besides, this is a scatter plot and not a [bar chart](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html).

Comment: Oh, sorry there is a typo. But, yes I tried it and have  them same message. <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x16c426190>

Comment: Also the `import` part?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted your corrected code: I am having this : '<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x10dd19790>'

Comment: I can run the code with Python 2.7 (interactive or script) without problems. Can you check your matplotlib version etc. via the [Troubleshooting](http://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html) page?

Answer (score 0):

It worked with the following code:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Good luck!